# Trying to fit a generalized additive mixed model (GAMM) to longitudinal neuroanatomic data

Tags: r, regression, mgcv

I am trying fit a generalized additive mixed model (GAMM) to longitudinal neuroanatomic data using the mgcv package in R. Some individuals have only two time points, while others have up to eight. The brain_data is formatted as such:

```
identifier age_at_scan brain_measure_x
1234       6.76        .452
1234       8.67        .789
5678       12.45       .987
5678       13.7        .234
5678       16.29       .423
```

My first goal is to use the GAMM to characterize the age-related changes in the brain measure of interest. Currently, I have the following code:

```
library(mgcv)

#the model:      
g1<-gamm(brain_measure_x~s(age_at_scan),data=brain_data,method='REML')
```

I am not sure if this model takes into account the fact that my data is longitudinal. If it does not, how do I need to change the code (e.g. would I add 'identifier' as the random term)?

Comment: This is really a question for Stack Exchange, not Stack Overflow, but I'd say there isn't a single right way to do this. You'll have to decide how you want to account for the panel nature of your data. But I would definitely start by trying a random intercept for `identifier`.

Comment: ah, okay great. I'll start with the intercept then for sure. and thank you for the direction on where this question could be better posted.

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386412/how-to-control-for-age-in-analyzing-longitudinal-data-using-mixed-effects-regres?rq=1) is one relevant Q&A on SE now.

Comment: @ulfelder Stack Exchange is the network of sites - better to refer this question specifically to Cross Validated, aka stats.stackexchange

Comment: But @PatrickD'Onofrio, the formulation you're using only accounts for the variables in your formula, `brain_measure_x` and `age_at_scan`. Adding  `+ (1 | identifier)` would add a random effect intercept for each `identifier`, which is at least a good place to start for accounting for the repeated measures.

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica--, on CV vs. SE, yeah, sorry, brain currently running at one-quarter speed...